# Inconsistent results calling sed on piped output using subprocess

Tags: python, bash, sed, subprocess

I'm translating a bash script for running computations and performing some postprocessing to Python, and have run into a hitch when I try to pipe program output into sed.  The issue centers around translating this sort of pipeline:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "whatever\n1 2" | ./a.out | sed -e 's/.* //'
```

where the executable is compiled from:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define FLUSH true

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string filename;
    int param1, param2;
    std::cout << "Input name of file: " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> filename;
    std::cout << "Enter params, separated by a space: " << std::flush;
    std::cin >> param1 >> param2;
    for(int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
        std::cout << "Result " << i << ": " << i*param1+i*i*param2/(param1+i) << "\n";
        if(FLUSH) {
            std::cout << std::flush;
        }   
    }   
}
```

I try the following

```
import subprocess
compute = subprocess.Popen(['./a.out'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
strip = subprocess.Popen(['sed','-e', 's/.* //'], stdin=compute.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = compute.communicate('filename.csv\n1 2')
print out
```

But instead of getting a list of raw outputs as expected, I get a random subsequence of the lines from the program output, such as:

```
Result 0: 0
Result 2: 4
Result 3: 7
Result 4: 10
Result 5: 13
Result 6: 16
Result 14: 40
...
Result 392: 1174
Result 396: 1186
Result 399: 1195
```

I'm not using random to mean arbitrary: the output varies from one execution of the script to the next.  Because of this, I assume the problem has something to do with the timing of the output buffer flushes, so that sed not receiving output lines one at a time --  this is why I was experimenting with variably flushing the buffer after each line.  However, this has not resolved the issue, and none of the examples I find online about using subprocess for this sort of task has mentioned this issue.  Is there perhaps some way to ensure that the second command is not run until the first has terminated, or to process the lines one at a time?

A second issue is why the sed script does not actually perform the desired substring removal in my toy example; it works fine in the real script I'm writing, although random strings are not being passed through the entire pipeline.

To be clear, the desired output would look like:

```
0
2
4
7
10
13
16
19
...
1183
1186
1189
1192
1195
```

Comment: Not an answer, but shouldn't your sed expression be `'s/^.*: //'`?

Comment: What happens when you add `bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True` to the Popen calls?

Comment: @Roadowl: The regexp is fine as is, since the program output always contains with a number preceded by a space at the end of each line. I'm glad to learn about the keyword args you suggested for Popen, but they didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is non-deterministic because two processes are reading **concurrently** from the same file (pipe)—`sed` and your driver.  The output you see is what your driver got, because you never even read from `strip.stdout`—which is why it’s not processed.

So `communicate` doesn’t work here, which is unfortunate because manually writing to `compute.stdin` will **deadlock** if `sed` is waiting on you to drain its output pipe.  (With input this small, that won’t happen, but it’s not safe in general.)  You might be able to cheat terribly by assigning one `Popen` object’s stream to the other before calling `communicate`; the other easy approach is to use another **thread** to write the input.  Yet other approaches are available like `select` or wrappers for it (or similar multiplexers) like `asyncio`.

You could also of course `communicate` with one process at a time (buffering everything) or just do the string trimming in your own process, but I assume you want the freedom to filter through a less trivial process.